# Refresh two partial views every few seconds

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4, jquery, VS for my development with c# code
I am trying to automatically refresh two partial views every few seconds. User can choose the interval at which they want to refresh the views. I have a dropdownlist with a few values like 5,10,30 which represents the seconds at which user wants the page refresh. Default is 5 seconds. I tried using setInterval

```
 setInterval(function () {
 $.get('/Home/Action1', {}, function (view) {
      $("#div1").html(view);
 })
 }, 10000);
 $.get('/Home/Action2', {}, function (view) {
      $("#div2").html(view);
 })
 }, 10000);
```

It is refreshing continuously even though I have given 10 seconds. I need to refresh two views and every few seconds only. I also need to be able to stop the refresh and restart the refresh when any popup is opened. Please advise.

thanks,

Comment: You have an erroneous `}, 10000);` which is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you Travis! I corrected it, but it is just calling the partialview continuously and the app is hanging. May be there is something else that is causing this to happen. Instead of refreshing every few seconds it is just calling the partialview nonstop. Any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You had is restarting every 10 seconds set it to 5000 to get 5 seconds.

```
 timer = setInterval(function () {
     $.get('/Home/Action1', {}, function (view) {
          $("#div1").html(view);
     })

     $.get('/Home/Action2', {}, function (view) {
          $("#div2").html(view);
     })
 }, 5000);
```

call this when you want to end it

```
 clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! I will correct my mistake and try. Will update the post.

Comment: Thank you again! I tried your code, but page hanging problem continues. It is refreshing the partialview nonstop instead of refreshing every few seconds.

Comment: Is there any errors showing up? If not try putting an alert in the set interval and see if the code is even being run. If the alert shows up its more than likely you ajax calls are failing

Comment: I put an alert and it is showing up. The frequency increases after the first time. I put a breakpoint in my MVC action method as well and I see that it is getting called continuosly.

Comment: Sorry, I did not knowingly down vote it. It might be a click by mistake. I appreciate your time. I am going to up vote it. I did not mean to down vote, it is by mistake.